# .NET MAUI Downsize image from camera before saving to gallery

Tags: .net, maui

I'm trying to bumble my way through making a cross platform camera app in .Net MAUI.

I've achieved everything I want so far, but the last step is having the app resize the image before saving.

I'm trying to understand how to use Microsoft.Maui.Graphics but there's just enough missing from my understanding of C# to have it elude me.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/graphics/images

This is what I have to capture and save the image. I presume I need to use Downsize on the captured stream before saving, but it doesn't seem to matter what I try, I just get errors.

```
async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var result = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync();

        setAsset();

        if (result != null)
        {
            using var stream = await result.OpenReadAsync();

            using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

            stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);

            stream.Position = 0;   
            memoryStream.Position = 0;

            var fName = projID.Text + "-" + assID.Text + "-" + wDetail.Text + ".jpg";



#if WINDOWS
            //await System.IO.File.WriteAllBytesAsync(@"C:\Users\dentk\Desktop\VenPhotos\" + fName, memoryStream.ToArray);
#elif ANDROID
            var context = Platform.CurrentActivity;
            if (OperatingSystem.IsAndroidVersionAtLeast(29))
            {
                Android.Content.ContentResolver resolver = context.ContentResolver;
                Android.Content.ContentValues contentValues = new();
                contentValues.Put(Android.Provider.MediaStore.IMediaColumns.DisplayName, fName);
                contentValues.Put(Android.Provider.MediaStore.IMediaColumns.MimeType, "image/jpg");
                contentValues.Put(Android.Provider.MediaStore.IMediaColumns.RelativePath, "DCIM/" + "test");
                Android.Net.Uri imageUri = resolver.Insert(Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri, contentValues);
                var os = resolver.OpenOutputStream(imageUri);
                Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.Options options = new();
                options.InJustDecodeBounds = true;
                var bitmap = Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(stream);
                bitmap.Compress(Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 60, os);
                os.Flush();
                os.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                Java.IO.File storagePath = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDcim);
                string pathIO = System.IO.Path.Combine(storagePath.ToString(), fName);
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(pathIO, memoryStream.ToArray());
                var mediaScanIntent = new Android.Content.Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionMediaScannerScanFile);
                mediaScanIntent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new Java.IO.File(pathIO)));
                context.SendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
            }
#elif IOS || MACCATALYST
            var image = new UIKit.UIImage(Foundation.NSData.FromArray(memoryStream.ToArray()));
            image.SaveToPhotosAlbum((image, error) =>
            {
            });
#endif

            fileSaveLoc.Text = fName;

            await GetCurrentLocation();
            if (latlong != null)
            {
                double lat = Math.Round(latlong.Latitude, 6);
                double lng = Math.Round(latlong.Longitude, 6);
                latlngRes.Text = lat.ToString() + " : " + lng.ToString();

            }
            else
            {
                latlngRes.Text = "Unable to Retreive Location";
            }
        }
    }
```

This seems so straightforward, but I just cannot get it integrated into my existing code:

```
using Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Platform;
...

IImage image;
Assembly assembly = GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("GraphicsViewDemos.Resources.Images.dotnet_bot.png"))
{
    image = PlatformImage.FromStream(stream);
}

// Save image to a memory stream
if (image != null)
{
    IImage newImage = image.Downsize(150, true);
    using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        newImage.Save(memStream);
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm guessing getting the existing memoryStream into an IImage is the key, but how do I do that?

```
......
            stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);

            stream.Position = 0;   
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            
            IImage image;

// something here to get memoryStream into image

            
            if (image != null)
            {
                IImage newImage = image.Downsize(150, true);
                using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    newImage.Save(memStream);
                }
            }

// something to continue and save memStream to continue on and save into the phones gallery

......
```

Comment: First, please read [ask] before posting.  Saying "I just get errors" without telling us **what specific errors you are getting** is extremely unhelpful.  Second, have you looked at the [many existing questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=maui+resize+image+site:stackoverflow.com) on this subject?

Comment: Coding in anything besides VBA is new to me. I need someone to fill in the gaps in the code I've given above, not worry about the errors I'm getting trying to piece together code from sources unknown.

Comment: I found (when using .NET 8) that using "newImage.Save(memStream)" is not enough when saving this to a file.  IImage.Save() puts the position of the destination stream to the END of the stream.  You must use "memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)" to reset the stream pointer allowing you to save the entire contents (e.g. when using a "memStream.CopyToAsync()" )

Answer (score 2):

I needed something similar, wasn't able to get exact compression but if the image was larger than a certain size then I downsized it to a max resolution

```
 private async Task<byte[]> ResizePhotoStream(FileResult photo)
        {
            byte[] result = null;

            using (var stream = await photo.OpenReadAsync())
            {
                if (stream.Length > _imageMaxSizeBytes)
                {
                    var image = PlatformImage.FromStream(stream);
                    if (image != null)
                    {
                        var newImage = image.Downsize(_imageMaxResolution, true);
                        result = newImage.AsBytes();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(stream))
                    {
                        result = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
                    }
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: at line:  var image = PlatformImage.FromStream(stream);
Can't find PlatformImage , it's showing error .  How to fix it?

Comment: It's not available on windows.  Should be in Maui.Graphics Image

Comment: NO nowhere available,

Comment: @VishvaVijay Add this around the code: 

#if !WINDOWS

#endif